# Simple GUI Windows Drag&Drop

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I'd like to make a simple GUI that offers buttons which I can drag and drop into other Windows applications such that this other applications receives a certain string depending on the button chosen.

What would be the easiest GUI framework for Python that allows this drag and drop?

Comment: Which have you worked with and what have you tried?  wxPython has full support for Drag & Drop events, in addition to the others mentioned in the answers.

Comment: I've only done some TkInter. I suppose I have to learn it anew anyway. So I need a very simple one where I have a chance to find online examples which show how to make widgets draggable and provide some text on dragging. I only need a list of buttons which provide draggable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the UI Libraries are likely to have support for this in some fashion.  In wxPython we allow List Items to be moved between various lists.  Things might look like this:

```
class JobList(VirtualList):
  def __init__(self, parent, colref = 'job_columns'):
    VirtualList.__init__(self, parent, colref)

  def _bind(self):
    VirtualList._bind(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self._startDrag)

  def _startDrag(self, evt):
    # Create a data object to pass around.
    data = wx.CustomDataObject('JobIdList')
    data.SetData(str([self.data[idx]['Id'] for idx in self.selected]))

    # Create the dropSource and begin the drag-and-drop.
    dropSource = wx.DropSource(self)
    dropSource.SetData(data)
    dropSource.DoDragDrop(flags = wx.Drag_DefaultMove)
```

Then, there's a ListDrop class that facilitates the dropping of things onto the lists:

```
class ListDrop(wx.PyDropTarget):
  """
    Utility class - Required to support List Drag & Drop.
    Using example code from http://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls.
  """
  def __init__(self, setFn, dataType, acceptFiles = False):
    wx.PyDropTarget.__init__(self)

    self.setFn = setFn

    # Data type to accept.
    self.data = wx.CustomDataObject(dataType)

    self.comp = wx.DataObjectComposite()
    self.comp.Add(self.data)

    if acceptFiles:
      self.data2 = wx.FileDataObject()
      self.comp.Add(self.data2)

    self.SetDataObject(self.comp)

  def OnData(self, x, y, d):
    if self.GetData():
      if self.comp.GetReceivedFormat().GetType() == wx.DF_FILENAME:
        self.setFn(x, y, self.data2.GetFilenames())
      else:
        self.setFn(x, y, self.data.GetData())

    return d
```

And finally, a List where things can be dropped:

```
class QueueList(VirtualList):
  def __init__(self, parent, colref = 'queue_columns'):
    VirtualList.__init__(self, parent, colref)

    self.SetDropTarget(ListDrop(self.onJobDrop, 'JobIdList', True))

  def onJobDrop(self, x, y, data):
    idx, flags = self.HitTest((x, y)) #@UnusedVariable

    if idx == -1: # Not dropped on a list item in the target list.
      return 

    # Code here to handle incoming data.
```

Comment: Looks promising. Is that intra-wxPython or will it work with other Windows Apps? Because all I really need is some draggable Label which will insert a string into onto Windows applications when dropped there. So I don't worry about being dropped and I don't need complex objects, just some string content...

Comment: @Gerenuk - The CustomDataObject was a better choice on mine, but you can use `wx.TextDataObject` or `wx.PyTextDataObject` as well.  You can find more information here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls#Drag_and_Drop_with_lists

Answer (score 1):

[PyQt to the rescue.](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/c8016)

Comment: I see :) However, I couldn't find and example to do the drag (not drop) and provide defined text. Could you help me find a reference? I don't know this framework :( .... EDIT: Ah its on the next page :) Hope it helps...

Comment: Wow, PyQt seems complicating :( I don't see a simple way to do the drag :(

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can use any library for which a graphical drag-and-drop designer exists. Such tools often generate markup language which the library parses, and sometimes they generate code directly. The latter is language-dependent whilst the former shouldn't be. Either way, you'll find a way of doing it with Python.

Practically, some libraries have better visual designing tools that others. WinForms designer was really elegant and seamless when I used it, so maybe IronPython? How about PyGTK, with Glade, or the aforementioned PyQt? Maybe Jython using Swing designed in NetBeans?

**EDIT:** Whoops, I didn't read the question properly. What you're looking for is a framework with drag-and-drop capabilities, i.e. most of them. There's lots of things to consider though, for example are the destination and source windows going to be from the same process? Will they be written with the same framework? These things could be relevant or not, depending on how it's all written.

Comment: It's different processes. Basically I want to drop text strings into an arbitrary Windows app. Most of them support that.